# Comparing nucleophilic strengths of tetrahydropyran and (2R,6R)-2,6 dimethyltetrahydropyran

Tags: organic-chemistry, heterocyclic-compounds, inductive-effect, nucleophilicity

> Compare the **nucleophilic strengths** of the following two compounds:
> [image]

According to me it should be the second one, that is, (2*R*,6*R*)-2,6-dimethyltetrahydropyran because the methyl groups would exert +I effect which would increase the electron density on the oxygen atom and hence it would become more nucleophilic, but the answer in my book is given as the first one. I don't understand why is it so. Is it because the effects of the methyl groups would cancel as they are connected in *trans* manner? But then I don't understand why would the first one still have a higher nucleophilicity.

Comment: The steric hindrance is a much more significant factor here than the inductive effect

Comment: It's similar to SIP effect. Search for SIP, there are many reputable sources with information on it.